# checking whether the values of two variables in data frame starts with particular numbers in r

Tags: r

I am trying to determine whether 2 variables in a data frame have values starting with 3 specific numbers for each row. If I have the following df:

```
a <- c(54012, 54412, 53030, 54012, ...)
b <- c(540, 540, 530, 520, ...) 
df <- cbind(a,b)
```

I'd like to return:

```
  a          b      same
54012       540     TRUE   #because values in variables a and b starts with 540
54412       540     FALSE #because values in variables a and b does not start with first 3 numbers
etc...
```

Comment: Your example data is a matrix, not a data frame, because you used `cbind`. Why not just use `df <- data.frame(a = c(54012, 54412, 53030, 54012), b = c(540, 540, 530, 520))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you can try `startsWith` like below

```
within(
  df,
  same <- Vectorize(startsWith)(as.character(a), as.character(b))
)
```

or `substr`

```
within(
  df,
  same <- substr(a, 1, nchar(b)) == b
)
```

or `str_detect` (thank @akrun's comment)

```
with(df, str_detect(a, as.character(b)))
```

which gives

```
      a   b  same
1 54012 540  TRUE
2 54412 540 FALSE
3 53030 530  TRUE
4 54012 520 FALSE
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(a = c(54012, 54412, 53030, 54012), b = c(540, 
540, 530, 520)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Or use `str_detect` `with(df, str_detect(a, as.character(b)))`

Answer (score 1):

Here are some other ways to solve your problem:

```
df <- data.frame(
  a = c(54012, 54412, 53030, 54012),
b = c(540, 540, 530, 520)
)
```

#### base r

```
df <- transform(df, same = substr(a, start=1, stop=3) == b)
```

#### data.table approach

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, same := substr(a, start=1, stop=3) == b]
```

#### dplyr approach

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(same = substr(a, start=1, stop=3) == b)
```

if `a` always has 5 digits, you can also replace `same = substr(a, start=1, stop=3) == b` with `same = (a %/% 100 == b)` in the above expressions. Something like:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, same := (a %/% 100 == b)]
```

etc.